# Cuda 6.0/PyCuda. 'ImportError'

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, python, shared-library, cuda

I had Cuda 5.5 with pycuda working great, but then I needed to upgrade to CUDA 6.0.

Now when I try to run a sample PyCuda program I get this :

```
ImportError: libcurand.so.6.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I found the path to that file, am I supposed to link this library somehow ? and if so, How ? and where to ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because the path of lib is not present in LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable.

To add this path to  LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable, open your `~/.bashrc` file using

`gedit ~/.bashrc`

and add the following line. Relace the `<path_to_your_lib>` with the path to the file.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:<path_to_your_lib>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Solution:** You need to add the path to the CUDA libraries to your `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.

#### Explanation:

When a CUDA program is executed, it needs to dynamically link to the CUDA runtime libraries. By default, these libraries are located in the `/usr/local/cuda/lib` directory. When searching for these libraries, the operating system looks in directories specified in the `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable. If the CUDA library directory is not specified here, the program will fail with the error shown above.

There are two solutions (these assume you are using the bash shell, which is the default CS Department shell):

1. Run the following command:

   ```
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib
   ```

   This change is not persistent and will need to be re-run each time you log in.
2. Edit your `.profile` file (located at `~/.profile`). Find the line that sets the `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable, which should look similar to the following:

   ```
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib:/usr/openwin/lib:/usr/dt/lib:/X11.6/lib:/X11.5/lib:/uva/lib:/gnu/lib"
   ```

   Modify that line to add the path to the CUDA libraries:

   ```
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib:/usr/openwin/lib:/usr/dt/lib:/X11.6/lib:/X11.5/lib:/uva/lib:/gnu/lib:/usr/local/cuda/lib"
   ```

   After editing the file, you either need to log out and log back in or run the following command:

   ```
    source ~/.profile
   ```

This solution is persistent and only needs to be performed once.

[source](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/%7Emwb7w/cuda_support/libcudart.html)